# how to invoke C++ functions from Javascript using QT/python?

Tags: javascript, c++, python, qt

I have an embedded system, whose GUI is developed using html. Inside, HTML, I am writing javascripts. Now, How can I invoke a C++ functions - middleware from Javascript using QT? I heard QT is the easiest way to invoke C++ functions from Javascript. Is there any example, that calls the C++ function from JAVA SCRIPT. I am completely new to python, Does python provides this functionality? Examples do help me. Please explain me via example. Additionally, the internal mechanism - to invoke C++ from Javascript will be helpful. Please ignore my python part, If I am sounding odd. As I am completely new to python. I really don't its power.

Let's say, I have the  middleware in CPP - for the demonstration purpose only one file.

```
#include "stdio.h"

class Sample
{

 private:

   int net_value;


public:


  Sample()
  {

    printf("constructor called\r\n");

  }



 void set_value()
  {
    net_value = 10;

  }


};
```

I have compiled this as following.

gcc -c -fPIC sample.cpp

gcc --shared sample.o  -o libmysample.so

Now, my HTML FILE.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function calculate() 
{ 
alert('You clicked the top text'); 
}

function functionTwo() 
{ alert('You clicked the bottom text'); 

}
  </script>
 </head>
<body>

<form action="http://136.170.195.17/cgi-bin/jordan_cgi.cgi">
<h1> Enter the First Equation </h1>
<input type=text name=val1 size=1>
X

+
<input type=text name=val2 size=1>
Y

+
<input type=text name=val3 size=1>
Z
=
<input type=text name=val4 size=1>
<h1> Enter the Second Equation </h1>
<input type=text name=val11 size=1>
X

+
<input type=text name=val12 size=1>
Y

+
<input type=text name=val13 size=1>
Z
=
<input type=text name=val14 size=1>

<h1> Enter the Third Equation </h1>
<input type=text name=va2l1 size=1>
X

+
<input type=text name=va2l2 size=1>
Y

+
<input type=text name=va2l3 size=1>
Z
=
<input type=text name=va2l4 size=1> <br>
<br>
<div><input type="submit" value="Compute!"></div>
</form> 

 </body>
</html>
```

Now, my interest is to invoke the void set_value() from the JAVASCRIPT Function.

function calculate() 
    {

```
  /** First instantiate Sample class and then invoke the set_value
 ---> Here I want to invoke set_value() -> remember the set_value is in the 
 .so file.  **/

alert('You clicked the top text'); 
}
```

How can I do achieve the above task? This example can be elaborated further for Callback part. This way, it becomes handy to call a C++ function to register callback and others. Please exemplify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inline C++ code in your javascript, a method cpp2js(code {, callback}) is provided in the file cpp2js.js. Include this file in your webpage:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="cpp2js.js"></script>
```

[Inline C++ functions in Javascript](http://www.speqmath.com/tutorials/cpp2js/index.html)

Comment: So, In case I have a middleware with all C++ functions and UI in html / java script. Then Do I need to run the cpp2js tool on the middleware library or where do I need to run this tool? Since I have to link the C++ function in middleware with the UI.

Comment: That cpp2js is a sample how you can achieve - go through to understand how you are going to call. You have not posted any code. There is very little info at my end. But the point is to write cpp code in *.js file call it in your Html code as <script ... </script>

Comment: I have added the sample as told by you. Hope, I will get the better response now. Thanks!